# "clipboard" in R always switches back to previous data - how to reset it?

Tags: r, clipboard

I wrote an R script that uses

```
> read.table("clipboard",header=TRUE)
```

to read data from clipboard. But strangely the clipboard always switches back in a to me undeterministic way to a previous clipboard. No matter how or from where I copied new data into the clipboard, running the script always sets the clipboard back to an old clipboard. How can I reset this? Is the clipboard somehow linked to a previous fixed value? If yes how can I refresh this value? The script only read data and makes a plot, I don't write any new data to the clipboard.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you run the script? The clipboard is for strictly interactive use of course

Comment: awesome, that was it. Running with source("script.R") it works. Thanks

Comment: I suspect Ctrl+R uses the clipboard, then.